# notifydatasetchanged() don't see scroll down effect

Tags: android, android-cardview

I try to do something like this : 
[image]

To expand or collapse my `cardView` I call the`notifydatasetchanged ()`method but I do this method resets the view to the first element and scroll very quickly to my old view. How can the user not see this scroll? To illustrate my problem here is a video : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7LMfg4tJlisVVlXajVuVlIyd3c

**My Adapter**

public class CardsViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private Game[] mDataset;
//    private boolean isPopupVisible = false;
    int rotationAngle = 0;

```
// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView mTextView;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public LinearLayout test2;
    public TextView test3;
    boolean isPopupVisible;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_cards);
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_description_game_more);
        test2 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.popup_layout);
        test3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.test_view);
        isPopupVisible = false;

    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public CardsViewAdapter(Game[] myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public CardsViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cards_resume_game, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    //...

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    //TODO : complete
    final int pos = position;
    holder.mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mDataset[position].getId_game()));
    holder.test3.setText("Position : "+pos);
    // Set the expanded or collapsed mode here
    if(mDataset[position].expanded)
        expandView(holder.test2,holder.imageView);
    else
        collapseView(holder.test2,holder.imageView);


    // Now set the onClickListener like this
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            // Animate the imageView here
            animateImageView(holder.imageView);

            // Toggle the expanded attribute value
            if(mDataset[pos].expanded) mDataset[pos].expanded = false;
            else mDataset[pos].expanded = true;

            // Now call notifyDataSetChanged to make the change to effect
            refreshList();
        }
    });



}

// Extra functions inside your adapter class to improve readability
private void collapseView(View v,ImageView imageView) {
    CardsAnimationHelper.collapse(v);
}


private void expandView(View v,ImageView imageView) {
    CardsAnimationHelper.expand(v);
}

private void animateImageView(ImageView imageView) {
    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "rotation",rotationAngle, rotationAngle + 180);
    anim.setDuration(animationDuration);
    anim.start();
    rotationAngle += 180;
    rotationAngle = rotationAngle % 360;
}

long animationDuration = 500;

private void refreshList() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, animationDuration);
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}
```

Comment: Don't use notifyDataSetChanged() method, give it a try:

    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Toggle the expanded attribute value
            if(mDataset[pos].expanded) mDataset[pos].expanded = false;
            else mDataset[pos].expanded = true;

if(mDataset[position].expanded)
        expandView(holder.test2,holder.imageView);
    else
        collapseView(holder.test2,holder.imageView);
        }
    });

Comment: Can you make a reply and I accept it after checking something

Comment: I would suggest to try it at first, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the RecyclerView's `notifyItemChanged(int position)` method then you're list won't refresh entirely.

To make is visually more attractive you can also use  `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in your layout file, this wil auto animate layoutchanges (https://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html).

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

`notifydatasetchanged()` doesnt scroll it just updates. use `recyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition(int position)` to scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can use two ways to scroll.

1. smoothScrollToPosition(int position) [If you want to achieve smoothscroll]
2. setSelection(int position)

Perform this action in post or postDelayed as per your requirement.